# Storing bullet points into mysql table

Tags: php

In my project there's a csv file uploading to store bulk data into the database table.

If the csv file has bullet points then the bullet points is not stored in table instead of that bullet point it storing as **?**

My output from csv file for single column (which has bullet points)

> A Foley catheter is a flexible tube passed through the urethra and 
>       into the bladder to drain urine. It is the most common type of 
>      indwelling urinary catheter. The tube of a Foley catheter has two 
>     separated channels, or lumens, running down its length. One lumen is open at both ends, and drains urine into a collection bag. The other lumen has a valve on the outside end and connects to a balloon at the tip. The balloon is inflated with sterile water when it lies inside the bladder to stop it from slipping out. Foley catheters are commonly made from silicone rubber or natural rubber.
>
> Key Product Types
>   ● Latex Catheter
>   ● Silicone Catheter
>
> Key Regions
>   ● North America
>   ● Europe
>   ● Asia Pacific
>
> Key Vendors
>   ● Teleflex
>   ● B.Braun
>   ● Bard
>   ● Karex Berhad
>   ● Coloplast
>   ● Bactiguard
>   ● Dentsply
>   ● Urovision
>   ● Medtronic
>   ● Welllead
>   ● Create Medic
>   ● ConvaTec
>   ● Zhanjiang Star
>   ● Fujian Bestway
>   ● Cook Medical
>   ● Hollister Incorporated
>   ● Pacific Hospital Supply
>   ● Bactiguard
>   ● Amsino International
>   ● Utah Medical Products
>
> Key Questions Answered in this Report
>   ● What will the market size be in 2022?
>   ● What are the key factors driving the global Foley catheter market?
>   ● What are the challenges to market growth?
>   ● Who are the key players in the Foley catheter market?
>   ● What are the market opportunities and threats faced by the key players?

I used coding like below to store values in table

```
addslashes(nl2br(iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", trim($data[12])))))
```

Its working fine but bullet points are not storing properly. Anyother way to achieve this.

Comment: If the charset is set properly to UTF-8, it has to work. Here in SO bulks are saved into database too :-)

Comment: Its already set as UTF-8 but its not working @panther